# How to convert military time to a whole time in PHP?

Tags: php, time

How to convert military time like this?

```
 07:03    -->   07:30
 06:45    -->   07:00
 07:36    -->   08:00

 19:15    -->   19:30
 18:35    -->   19:00
 19:35    -->   20:00
```

Basically the thing is, if the time is in the interval of 30 mins, you will add up the remaining minutes to make it a whole time.

In my database, I have to compare time like this where:

```
function check_range($get_shift, $date, $time, $id, $mode) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_employee WHERE id = '$id'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    $row_check_range = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    $getShift = $row_check_range['shift'];

    $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM tbl_shift WHERE shift = '$getShift'";
    $result2 = mysql_query($sql2);
    $row_check_range2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($result2);
    $getTimeShift = $row_check_range2['timeIn'];

    $actual_time_in_mode = explode(':', $time); //split time into (e.g 07, 11)
    if ($mode == 'AM') {
        $time_in_actual = $actual_time_in_mode[0];
    } else {
        $time_in_actual = $actual_time_in_mode[0];
        $time_shift = explode(':', $getTimeShift);
        $getTimeShift = $time_shift[0] + 12; //convert to military time
    }

    $getTimeShift = mktime($getTimeShift);
    $actual_in_mode = mktime($time);

    if ($actual_in_mode > $getTimeShift) // LATE
    {
        return $date.' '.$time_in_actual.':30:00';
    } else {
        $time_in_actual += 1;
        return $date.' '.$time_in_actual.':00:00';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function military_time($x){
$y=split(':',$x);
$y[0] =(((int)$y[1]) >30) ? ((int)$y[0])+1 : $y[0];
$y[0] =((int) $y[0] == 24) ? '00':$y[0];
$y[0]=(strlen($y[0]) == 1) ? '0'.$y[0] : $y[0];
$y[1] =(((int)$y[1]) >30) ? '00':'30';
echo $y[0].':'.$y[1];
}
military_time('23:35');
```

Comment: i don't why are people are jealous and then they DownVote coz there answer was un-selected .

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do.

```
list($hour, $minute) = explode(':', $time);

if ($minute > 30) {
    $hour++;
    $minute = 0;
} elseif ($minute > 0) {
    $minute = 30;
}

if ($hour == 24) $hour = 0;

printf('%02d:%02d', $hour, $minute);
```

Comment: You can make the code a little bit shorter. `$hour++;` to `$hour = ($hour + 1) % 24`. Then, remove the `if ($hour == 24) $hour = 0;`.

Answer (score 0):

Just add 30 minutes and then round the number DOWN to the closest `:30` or `:00`.

Comment: No, that would make 1:20 into 1:50 and be rounded to 2:00, when it should be 1:30.

Comment: @ironcito - that's true.

Comment: Adding 30 and rounding down is the same as rounding up, which is what he is trying to do ;)

Comment: I like Rob's answer better. :)